# Mostly played online or Played mostly online

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-order

Which version is the best:

1. Mostly played online
2. Played mostly online

Can we say both?

Answer (score 3):

Both are fine. The word order doesn't matter in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either of the two, option one is better though, because it's less of a tongue-twister. As well as that fact that it allows easier breathing when saying it, because the the most emphasized word is in the middle.

> Mostly played online